# cant get custom taxonomy urls to work in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

As The Title said,

I tried to implement a custom taxonomy in wordpress, i followed the tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/ by the letter for that, my code to add the taxonomy is (placed it in a plugin as well as in the templates function php. to no avail):

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );  

function build_taxonomies() {  
    register_taxonomy( 'operating_system', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Operating System', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );  
}
```

After that I can add terms to that taxonomy, and select them for posts, all fine, but whatevery i try, I'm not able to get a listing for the "tagged" posts,s ee for yourself:

http://sandbox.lautr.com/hello-world-2

The new term here would be Operating System(s): -> OS <-

And yes, there is a taxonomy.php for the Template but it looks like its not called at all ... I really can't see what I've done wrong, I'm using Wordpress Version 3.0.2

EDIT:

Okay, i found my mistake, for whatever obscure Reason Category base under permalinks has to be set to *something* even if its just the default anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found my mistake, for whatever obscure Reason Category base under permalinks has to be set to something even if its just the default anyway!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic uhm, yeah, you are aware that you have to wait 2 days till you can do that, right?